# Busca linear recursiva c++

Tags: c++

Queria fazer uma busca linear recursiva usando vector e iteradores, aqui vai o código:

```
long int busca_sr(std::vector<long int> &amostra, const long int &key){
    auto first = amostra.begin();
    auto last = amostra.end();
    if (last == first-1){
        return -1;
    }
    else if(*last == key){
        return 1;
    }
    else{ 
        --last;
        std::vector <long int> auxi1 (first, last);
        return busca_sr(auxi1, key); 

    }
```

O problema é que quando eu executo essa função o meu pc trava, eu suspeito que o erro esta na condição de parada da minha recursão, pois quando o last for igual ao first o vector auxiliar la em baixo não será alocado, queria uma forma de inserir uma condição de parada sem ter que mudar a assinatura da função!

Comment: Você não deve desreferenciar o valor de end(), o que ocorre em *last == key. fonte: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/end/

Answer (score 0):

Como é uma busca linear, acho que é mais natural você começar a verificação a partir do primeiro elemento e ir avançando o iterador do inicio em 1 em vez de começar pelo último elemento.

Outro ponto que estava errado era o critério de parada: a condição `if(last == first-1)` sempre dá exceção, pois você está tentando ler um índice antes do primeira posição. Para averiguar se o iterador chegou no fim do vector, basta fazer a verificação `v.begin() == v.end()`.

```
long int busca_sr(std::vector<long int> &amostra, const long int &key) {
    std::vector<long int>::iterator first = amostra.begin();
    std::vector<long int>::iterator last = amostra.end();

    if (last == first) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (*first == key) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        std::vector <long int> auxi1(++first, last);
        return busca_sr(auxi1, key);
    }
}
```